# Comparing duplicates and choosing the duplicate with most recent date in a join

Tags: oracle, join, oracle-12c, duplication

Assume i have table A:

```
id:    name:    timestamp:
1      Bob      2018-05-31 04:46:37
2      Alice    2019-01-31 07:13:56
1      Bob      2019-01-15 18:23:74
```

And i want to join with another table B:

```
id:    name:    Preference:
1      Bob      Car
2      Alice    Bike
```

ID alone isnt a primary key. however ID + timestamp IS an unique key. However, how would i make to only join the 1 part of the duplicate, that has a the newest date? So that i would get a joined table like:

```
id:    name:    Preference:    Timestamp:
1      Bob      Car            2019-01-15 18:23:34
2      Alice    Bike           2019-01-31 07:13:56
```

By if i have duplicates, then compare the date between the duplicates and choose the newst

Comment: the duplicate rows in the second table was a mistake on my part, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `LATERAL` join or `CROSS APPLY` (both added in version 12c) or window ranking functions in a subquery which should work in older versions as well:

```
WITH cte AS
( 
    SELECT 
        b.id, b.name, b.preference, 
        a.timestamp,         -- keep only columns you need
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b.id
                           ORDER BY a.timestamp DESC)
          AS rn
    FROM b 
         LEFT JOIN a
         ON b.id = a.id
)
SELECT cte.*           -- keep only columns you need
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
-- ORDER BY b.id
 ;
```

Comment: Using ur example and using it almost 1:1, i keep getting the error of column ambigously defined, however i can't see why

Comment: You need to keep only the columns you need in the subquesry You have `a.id` and `b.id` (and `a.name` and `b.name)`, so at least two columns with same name.keep only one of them in the subquery. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation together with "KEEP LAST". It will pick last value of column from a group ordered by another column.

```
select a.id
  , a.name
  , max(b.preference) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY A.TIMESTAMP)
  , max(a.timestamp)
from A
join B on (a.id = b.id and a.name=b.name)
group by a.id, a.name
```

PS: your example seems to be ambiguous is "name" also a key?

Comment: No name is not supposed to be a key, as 2 completely random people might have the same name, sorry for the ambiguity